# Side By Side Two controls CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to Place two dx:ASPxDateEdit side by side as From Date and To Date How can i achieve

```
    <td>Issues Date:</td>
     <td>
      <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="deFromDate" runat="server" Width="100px" AllowUserInput="False" Height="25px"
                    EditFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" DisplayFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" EditFormat="Custom"
                    Theme="Office2003Blue" ClientInstanceName="deFromDate" OnInit="deFromDate_Init">
      </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="deToDate" runat="server" Width="100px" AllowUserInput="False" Height="25px"
                    EditFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" DisplayFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" EditFormat="Custom"
                    Theme="Office2003Blue" ClientInstanceName="deFromDate" OnInit="deFromDate_Init">
      </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

[image]

Comment: No its not html it is a Devex DateEdit

Comment: @ppwater <dx:ASPxDateEdit Is Devexpress Control its not an HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom css to the datepickers with a class name like this to both of them:

Added css Class in

```
 <dx:ASPxDateEdit CssClass="date"
```

For Both `dx:ASPxDateEdit` and Added bellow `style` and its working as expected

```
.datepicker{
display:inline-block;
}
```

or

```
 <style>
    .date {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Its not working datepicker is not present in my Code Please check once

Comment: in your inspect element of your browser, check the HTML element which is rendered for this controller. check for id or class name that it has. use them with `important` in your stylesheet. ir if you can add a custom CSS class name to the Devex component.

Answer (score 1):

Give `<dx:ASPxDateEdit>` a class of `.date`

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit
      class="date"
        ID="deToDate"
        runat="server"
        Width="100px"
        AllowUserInput="False"
        Height="25px"
        EditFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy"
        DisplayFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy"
        EditFormat="Custom"
        Theme="Office2003Blue"
        ClientInstanceName="deFromDate"
        OnInit="deFromDate_Init"
      >
      </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

and then give your class the property `display:inline`

```
 .date {
        display: inline;
      }
```

OR if you want to show it on separate lines.

```
 .date {
        display: block;
      }
```

Comment: Should I add Class in both <dx:DateEdit

Comment: I have added in both Control but instead of one Line its appearing One Up and Another Down

Comment: Add display:inline;